# GIT Commit Limbo Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2015

A team and I are working on finalizing a project and we are in a predicament where I cannot pull or commit any changes. One of my team members committed and pushed changes out to the master and I did not know. I then proceed to try and commit and push my changes and I got a message along the lines of

`Unable to push to local changes because changes exist on remote`

So I tried to pull in the changes but then it says that I can't pull in any changes because I have local commits... I tried reverting my commits and I thought that would undo my local commits but I'm not really sure what it did honestly because I have the same problem still.

So I switched to a different local branch and deleted my local master and tried re-checking out the master from remote hoping that I would just get the new changes. But instead Visual Studio presents me with this message:

`Cannot switch to master because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before you switch branches. See the Output window for details.`
And the output window cites two classes that are just designer.cs classes that I actually did not explicitly change (I just changed the non-designer.cs class).

I found several other posts involving this issue with `VS2012`, `VS2013`, but I'm on `VS2015` and I'm not sure I know how to resolve this from the other posts I saw. I am new to GIT (Use SVN daily) so I'm a little lost and confused about what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was right under my nose. Apparently two classes were "untracked" and by simply right-clicking and selecting ignore, I was able to successfully switch to my local master branch and pull in the new changes.

A newbie answer for a newbie question. Live and learn, hopefully my simple answer and Milen's answer can help the next poor soul that runs into the silly problem I had.

Answer (score 2):

You can stash your changes, pull latest from master, unstash your changes back and commit. Have a look [in here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/howto)  for more details.

Comment: But I can't switch to master in order to save any changes...that I know of. And none  of my other branches have any changes either.